How do I test view models for Android? I've been struggling with this for over a week
I am trying to test view model classes for my app. They use viewModelScope.launch and when I run tests using Firebase emulator, data will sometimes go to Firebase and sometimes won't resulting in failed tests even though I know the method works when I run the app. Any help is appreciated, thanks! I have read over the past week about testing coroutines via articles and through Android's documentation and how you can use StandardTestDispatcher and inject the dispatcher like so: viewModelScope.launch(dispatcher) but this is not working consistently. When I test the code that's inside viewModelScope it works but dealing with viewModelScope is where I am having issues. I've also used advanceUntilIdle() and dispatcher.schedule.advanceUntilIdle() Am I not supposed to test the view model this way? I know the code to update and retrieve from Firebase is working fine. It's just the testing I'm having issues with. Here is the code below. Can anyone spot any issues or should I just work around not testing view models?
The error I get is an assertion error based on the test I created that should return true but doesn't because the code being ran does not complete due to the issue I'm having testing in view model classes.
This is the Bookmark ViewModel test class
class BookmarkViewModelTest {

    private lateinit var roomDatabase: RoomDatabase
    private lateinit var context: Context
    private lateinit var firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var firebaseFirestore: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage
    private lateinit var userDao: UserDao
    private lateinit var firebaseRepository: FirebaseRepository
    private lateinit var bookmarkDao: BookmarkDao
    private lateinit var bookmarkLocalDataSource: BookmarkLocalDataSource
    private lateinit var bookmarkRemoteDataSource: BookmarkRemoteDataSource
    private lateinit var bookmarkRepository: BookmarkRepository
    private lateinit var bookmarkViewModel: BookmarkViewModel
    private lateinit var userLocalDataSource: UserLocalDataSource
    private lateinit var userRemoteDataSource: UserRemoteDataSource
    private lateinit var userRepository: UserRepository

    @Before
    fun setUp() = runTest {

        context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context

        roomDatabase = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(
            context, AppDatabase::class.java // Use your actual database class
        ).allowMainThreadQueries().build()

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseModule.provideFirebaseAuth()
        firebaseAuth.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9099)

        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseModule.provideFirestore()
        try {
            firebaseFirestore.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 8080)
        } catch (_: IllegalStateException) {
        }
        val settings = FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
            .setHost("10.0.2.2:8080") // Use 10.0.2.2 for Android emulators
            .setSslEnabled(false).build()
        firebaseFirestore.firestoreSettings = settings

//        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseModule.provideFirestore()
//        try {
//            firebaseFirestore.useEmulator("192.168.1.102", 8080)
//        } catch (_: IllegalStateException) {
//        }
//        firebaseFirestore.firestoreSettings = firestoreSettings {}

        firebaseStorage = FirebaseModule.provideStorage()
        firebaseStorage.useEmulator("10.0.2.2", 9199)

        userDao = (roomDatabase as AppDatabase).userDao()
        bookmarkDao = (roomDatabase as AppDatabase).bookmarkDao()

        userLocalDataSource = FakeUserLocalDataSourceImpl(firebaseAuth, userDao)
        userRemoteDataSource =
            FakeUserRemoteDataSourceImpl(firebaseAuth, firebaseFirestore, firebaseStorage)

        bookmarkLocalDataSource = BookmarkLocalDataSource(firebaseAuth, bookmarkDao)
        bookmarkRemoteDataSource = FakeBookmarkRemoteDataSourceImpl(firebaseAuth, firebaseFirestore)

        userRepository = FakeUserRepositoryImpl(userLocalDataSource, userRemoteDataSource)

        bookmarkRepository =
            FakeBookmarkRepositoryImpl(bookmarkLocalDataSource, bookmarkRemoteDataSource)

        firebaseRepository =
            FakeFirebaseRepositoryImpl(firebaseAuth, firebaseFirestore, firebaseStorage)

        // 10.0.2.2 is the special IP address to connect to the 'localhost' of
// the host computer from an Android emulator.

        val userData: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
        val mediaItems: MutableMap<String, Uri> = mutableMapOf()

        userData["id"] = "John"
        userData["displayName"] = "John"
        userData["userName"] = "John"

        (userRepository as FakeUserRepositoryImpl).saveUserData(
            "John", userData, mediaItems, context
        )

        bookmarkViewModel =
            BookmarkViewModel(
                firebaseRepository, bookmarkRepository, userRepository
            )

//        val bookmark = Bookmark("John", mutableListOf("Zeko", "Marc"))
//
//        bookmarkLocalDataSource.bookmarkDao.upsert(bookmark)

    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun fetchBookmarks() = runTest {

        var bookmarks = mutableListOf<String>()

        val bookmarkData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

        bookmarkData["bookmark-Ron"] = "Ron"
        bookmarkData["bookmark-Von"] = "Von"

        bookmarkViewModel.saveAndStoreBookmark("John", bookmarkData)

        advanceUntilIdle()

        bookmarkViewModel.fetchBookmarks().collect {
            bookmarks = it.toMutableList()
            Log.d("BookmarkViewModelTest", "bookmarks are $bookmarks")
        }

        advanceUntilIdle()

        Assert.assertTrue(bookmarks.contains("Ron") && bookmarks.contains("Von"))

    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun fetchUpdatedBookmarks() = runTest {

        var bookmarks = mutableListOf<String>()

        val bookmarkData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

        bookmarkData["bookmark-Crispus"] = "Crispus"
        bookmarkData["bookmark-Yao"] = "Yao"

        bookmarkViewModel.saveAndStoreBookmark("John", bookmarkData)

        advanceUntilIdle()

        bookmarkViewModel.fetchUpdatedBookmarks().collect {
            bookmarks = it.toMutableList()
        }

        Assert.assertTrue(bookmarks.contains("Crispus") && bookmarks.contains("Yao"))

    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun loadBookmarks() = runTest {

        Log.d("BookmarkViewModelTest", "all users = ${userDao.getAll()}")

        val bookmarkData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

        bookmarkData["bookmark-Arizona"] = "Arizona"

        bookmarkRepository.saveAndStoreBookmark("John", bookmarkData)

        advanceUntilIdle()

        bookmarkViewModel.loadBookmarks()

        advanceUntilIdle()

        val bookmarks = bookmarkViewModel.uiState.value.bookmarks

        Log.d("BookmarkViewModelTest", "bookmarks are $bookmarks")

        Assert.assertTrue(bookmarks.contains("Arizona"))

    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun getBookmarks() = runTest {

        var bookmarks = mutableListOf<String>()

        val bookmarkData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

        bookmarkData["bookmark-Maison"] = "Maison"
        bookmarkData["bookmark-Margela"] = "Margela"
        bookmarkData["bookmark-Zion"] = "Zion"

        bookmarkRepository.saveAndStoreBookmark("John", bookmarkData)

        advanceUntilIdle()

        bookmarkViewModel.getBookmarks().collect {
            bookmarks = it.toMutableList()
        }

        advanceUntilIdle()

        Assert.assertTrue(bookmarks.contains("Zion"))
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun saveAndStoreBookmark() = runTest {
        var bookmarks = mutableListOf<String>()

        val bookmarkData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

        bookmarkData["bookmark-Rodericka"] = "Rodericka"
        bookmarkData["bookmark-Kwesiana"] = "Kwesiana"

        bookmarkViewModel.saveAndStoreBookmark("John", bookmarkData)

        bookmarkViewModel.fetchBookmarks().collect {
            bookmarks = it.toMutableList()
        }

        advanceUntilIdle()

        Log.d(
            "BookmarkViewModelTest",
            "bookmarks inside saveAndStoreBookmark in test are ${bookmarkViewModel.uiState.value.bookmarks}"
        )

        Assert.assertTrue(bookmarks.contains("Rodericka") && bookmarks.contains("Kwesiana"))
    }

    @OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
    @Test
    fun removeBookmark() = runTest {

        var bookmarks = mutableListOf<String>()

        val bookmarkData = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()

        bookmarkData["bookmark-Rodericka"] = "Rodericka"

        bookmarkViewModel.saveAndStoreBookmark("John", bookmarkData)

        advanceUntilIdle()

        bookmarkViewModel.removeBookmark("Rodericka")

        advanceUntilIdle()

        bookmarkViewModel.getBookmarks().collect {
            bookmarks = it.toMutableList()
        }

        Log.d("BookmarkViewModelTest", "bookmarks inside removeBookmark in test are $bookmarks")

        advanceUntilIdle()

        Assert.assertTrue(bookmarks.contains("Rodericka"))
    }


    @Test
    fun getUiState() {
    }


    @Test
    fun fetchBookmarkObject() {
    }


    @Test
    fun storeBookmark() {
    }

    @Test
    fun storeBookmarkObject() {
    }

    @Test
    fun storeBookmarkInRoom() {
    }

    @Test
    fun saveUserDataToFirebase() {
    }

    @Test
    fun saveBookmarkToFirebase() {
    }

    @Test
    fun removeBookmarkFromFirebase() {
    }


    @Test
    fun getBookmarksFromFirebase() {
    }

    @Test
    fun convertBookmarksToList() {
    }

}

Here is the Bookmark ViewModel class
data class BookmarkUiState(
    val bookmarks: List<String> = emptyList(),
    val isLoading: Boolean = false,
    val errorMessage: String? = null
)


//sealed interface UsersUiState {
//    object Loading : UsersUiState
//    data class Success(val users: List<User>) : UsersUiState
//
////    data class Error(val errorMessage: ErrorMessage) : UsersUiState
//
//    data class Error(val errorMessage: String) : UsersUiState
//
//}

@HiltViewModel
class BookmarkViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseRepository: FirebaseRepository,
    private val bookmarkRepository: BookmarkRepository,
    private val userRepository: UserRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow(BookmarkUiState())
    val uiState: StateFlow<BookmarkUiState> = _uiState.asStateFlow()

    init {
        try {
            loadBookmarks()
        } catch (npe: NullPointerException) {
            Log.d("BookmarkViewModel", "bookmarks: $npe")
        }
    }

//    private val userDao = RoomModule.provideUserDao(appDatabase)
//    val bookmarkDao = RoomModule.provideBookmarkDao(appDatabase)


//    suspend fun fetchListOfBookmarksFromRepo(bookmarkId: String) {
//        firebaseRepository.fetchListOfBookmarks(bookmarkId)
//    }

//    fun fetchListOfBookmarksFromRoomDB(bookmarkId: String): String {
//        return bookmarkDao.findById(bookmarkId).bookmarks
//    }

//    fun saveBookmarksToRoomDB(bookmarks: String) : String {
//        bookmarkDao.insert(bookmarks)
//    }


    fun loadBookmarks() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                bookmarkRepository.fetchUpdatedBookmarks().collect { returnedBookmarks ->
                    Log.d("BookmarkViewModel", "fetch returns $returnedBookmarks")
                    _uiState.value = BookmarkUiState().copy(bookmarks = returnedBookmarks)
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                _uiState.value =
                    BookmarkUiState().copy(errorMessage = e.message ?: "Unknown error")
            }
        }
    }

    fun fetchBookmarkObject(): Bookmark {
        return bookmarkRepository.getBookmark(bookmarkRepository.getYourUserId())
    }

    suspend fun fetchBookmarks(): Flow<List<String>> {
        return bookmarkRepository.fetchBookmarks()
    }

    suspend fun fetchUpdatedBookmarks(): Flow<List<String>> {
        return bookmarkRepository.fetchUpdatedBookmarks()
    }


//    suspend fun fetchBookmarkFromRoom(bookmarkId: String): Bookmark {
//        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
//            try {
//                val bookmark = bookmarkDao.findById(bookmarkId)
//                if (bookmark != null) {
//                    Log.d("bookmarkViewModel", "fetch returns $bookmark")
//                    bookmark
//                } else {
//                    // Handle case when bookmark is null in the database
//                    val emptyBookmark = Bookmark(bookmarkId, mutableListOf())
//                    emptyBookmark
//                }
//            } catch (npe: NullPointerException) {
//                try {
//                    val bookmarkList = getBookmarksFromFirebase(bookmarkId)
//                    if (bookmarkList.isNotEmpty()) {
//                        Bookmark(bookmarkId, bookmarkList.toMutableList())
//                    } else {
//                        // Handle case when no data is available from Firebase
//                        // For example, you can return the existing bookmark object without modification
//                        val bookmark = Bookmark(bookmarkId, mutableListOf())
//                        bookmark
//                    }
//                } catch (npe: NullPointerException) {
//                    val bookmark = Bookmark(bookmarkId, mutableListOf())
//                    bookmark
//                }
//            }
//        }
//    }


    fun storeBookmark(userId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookmarkRepository.storeBookmark(userId)
        }
    }

    fun storeBookmarkObject(bookmark: Bookmark) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookmarkRepository.storeBookmarkObject(bookmark)
        }
    }

    fun storeBookmarkInRoom(bookmark: Bookmark) {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            bookmarkRepository.storeBookmarkObject(bookmark)
        }
    }

    fun saveUserDataToFirebase(
        userId: String,
        userData: MutableMap<String, Any>,
        mediaItems: MutableMap<String, Uri>,
        context: Context
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                val success =
                    firebaseRepository.writeUserDataToFirebase(
                        userId,
                        userData,
                        mediaItems,
                        context
                    )
                if (success) {
                    Log.d(
                        "BookmarkViewModel",
                        "User data successfully added at the time the userData includes $userData" +
                                "and the mediaItems include $mediaItems"
                    )
//                 Handle successful data save
                } else {
                    Log.d("BookmarkViewModel", "User data not added")
//                 Handle data save error
                }
            }
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveBookmarkToFirebase(
        bookmarkId: String,
        bookmarkData: MutableMap<String, Any>,
        context: Context
    ): Boolean {
        val success = firebaseRepository.writeBookmarksToFirebase(bookmarkId, bookmarkData)
        if (success) {
            val receivingUser = userRepository.getUser(bookmarkId)

            val userData: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
            val mediaItems: MutableMap<String, Uri> = mutableMapOf()

            receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount = receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount?.plus(1)

            userData["timesBookmarkedCount"] = receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount ?: 0

//            userViewModel.saveUserDataToFirebase(bookmarkId, userData, mediaItems, context) {
//                userViewModel.storeUserInRoom(yourUserId)
//            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Bookmark added!")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bookmark failed to be added!")
        }
        return success
    }

    suspend fun removeBookmarkFromFirebase(
        bookmarkId: String,
        context: Context
    ): Boolean {
        val success = firebaseRepository.deleteBookmarkFromFirebase(bookmarkId)
        if (success) {
            val receivingUser = userRepository.getUser(bookmarkId)

            val userData: MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf()
            val mediaItems: MutableMap<String, Uri> = mutableMapOf()

            receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount = receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount?.minus(1)

            if (receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount!! < 0) {
                receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount = 0
            }

            userData["timesBookmarkedCount"] = receivingUser.timesBookmarkedCount ?: 0

//            userViewModel.saveUserDataToFirebase(bookmarkId, userData, mediaItems, context) {
//                userViewModel.storeUserInRoom(yourUserId)
//            }

            Log.d(TAG, "Bookmark deleted!")
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Bookmark failed to be deleted!")
        }
        return success
    }

    suspend fun getBookmarks(): Flow<List<String>> {
        return bookmarkRepository.getBookmarks()
    }

    suspend fun getBookmarksFromFirebase(bookmarkId: String): List<String> {
        Log.d(TAG, "Going through BookmarkViewModel to get the Bookmark!")
        return firebaseRepository.getBookmarksFromFirebase(bookmarkId)
    }

    fun convertBookmarksToList(bookmarks: String): List<String> {
        return bookmarks.split(",")
    }

    fun saveAndStoreBookmark(
        bookmarkId: String,
        bookmarkData: MutableMap<String, Any>
    ) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                Log.d("BookmarkViewModel", "inside save and store where bookmarkId is $bookmarkId")
                Log.d(
                    "BookmarkViewModel",
                    "inside save and store where bookmarkData is $bookmarkData"
                )
                bookmarkRepository.saveAndStoreBookmark(bookmarkId, bookmarkData)
                loadBookmarks()
            }
        }
    }

    fun removeBookmark(bookmarkId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                bookmarkRepository.removeBookmark(bookmarkId)
                loadBookmarks()
            }

        }
    }

}


"where I am having issues" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Yeah, my bad. I never was able to add the code. I don't have any errors other than the test failing but I've walked through the code and my only issue seems to be getting through the viewmodelscope in order for the code to be able to finish and pass. @AlexMamo I was able to add some code for reference of how it's done.
